# How to selectively display and not display column of object in BindingList which is bond to gridcontrol of devexpress winform？

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol

Dear all devexpress winform gurus:)

My way is simple. First, i create a bindinglist:

```
 private BindingList<QuoteOnGrid> quoteOnGrids = new BindingList<QuoteOnGrid>();
```

Then my object called quote will be added to the BindingList above, the quote have multiple properties and will be displayed on the grid after binding code below:

```
 gridControl1.DataSource = quoteOnGrids;
```

The picture below show how manually remove column

[a busy cat http://i.minus.com/i1JuwLqAdWy2K.jpg](http://i.minus.com/i1JuwLqAdWy2K.jpg)

How could I disable the displaying of last three property of these financial quote object without removing these properties?:)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the [GridColumn.Visible](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_Visibletopic) property:

```
//...
    gridControl1.DataSource = new BindingList<Person>();
    gridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
}
//...
class Person {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you are the hero on devexpress application. Thanks again!!